# How to disable ripple effect on getmdl's toggle?

Tags: javascript, css, togglebutton, material-design-lite

I'm using `getmdl.io` component library, and I can't find a way to disable ripple effect on toggle component.

My HTML code looks like this:

```
<label class="mdl-switch mdl-js-switch" for="switch-1" id='switch-main'>
        <input type="checkbox" id="switch-1" class="mdl-switch__input" checked>
        <span class="mdl-switch__label"></span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this css into your code:

```
//for checkoox:
.mdl-ripple{
    visibility: hidden !important;
}
//for switch
.mdl-switch__input{
    visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

It seems that the library injects "span.mdl-ripple" tag into your span.mdl-switch__label to achieve the effect. We can set its visibility to hide it without impacting the layout.

Comment: this is not working, [see JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zhyw75us/)

Comment: Seems u didn't import the "getmdl.io" into your jsfiddle.

Comment: okay I did now, somehow it had got removed, but I can't see a difference by adding your css. [see JsFiddle Demo 2](https://jsfiddle.net/zhyw75us/1/)

Comment: Seems there's no ripple effect in your demo. Maybe I didn't get what kind of ripple effect did u mean.

Comment: by "ripple" I mean that short radial animation when clicked. like a circle that shows for a fraction of second when clicked.